# Comparing GenericTypeDefinition of interfaces

Tags: c#, generics, types

Simple code that I expect `List<int>`'s GenericTypeDefinition to contain a generic interface of `ICollection<>`. Yet I can't derive an acceptable type from `List<int>` which allows me to compare them properly.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var a = typeof(List<int>);
        var b = typeof(ICollection<>);

        var r1 = a.GetGenericTypeDefinition().GetInterfaces();
        foreach (var x in r1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine(b);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine(r1.Any(x => x == b));
    }
}
```

Output

```
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T]
System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList`1[T]
System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyCollection`1[T]
System.Collections.IEnumerable
System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[T]
System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[T]
System.Collections.ICollection
System.Collections.IList

System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[T]

False
```

I would have expected that `r1` contained a type that was equal to `b`.

**EDIT**

Fixed, Jon Skeet gave me the right insight into what was happening.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var a = typeof(List<int>);
        var b = typeof(ICollection<>);

        var r1 = a.GetInterfaces()
            .Where(x => x.IsGenericType)
            .Select(x => x.GetGenericTypeDefinition());

        foreach (var x in r1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine(b);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine(r1.Contains(b));


    }
}
```

Output

```
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T]
System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList`1[T]
System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyCollection`1[T]
System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[T]
System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[T]

System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[T]

True
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the generic type definition will refer to `ICollection<T>` specifically, where `T` is the type parameter for the `IList<T>`.

Imagine you had something like:

```
public class Foo<T1, T2> : IEnumerable<T1>, IComparable<T2>
```

The generic type definition contains all that information - it "knows" that it's specifically `IEnumerable<T1>` and `IComparable<T2>`, not `IEnumerable<T2>` and `IComparable<T1>` for example.

You can fix the check by getting the generic type definition for each of the interfaces implemented by the type:

```
Console.WriteLine(r1.Any(x => x.IsGenericType && 
                              x.GetGenericTypeDefinition()  == b));
```

Comment: Thank you, you gave me the insight I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try below line..

```
 Console.WriteLine(r1.Any(x => x.Name == b.Name));
```

Instead of

```
Console.WriteLine(r1.Any(x => x == b));
```

Comment: Not the safest of type comparison.

Comment: As Jon has just pointed out the T identifier in the Name string is not necessarily the same T as in the other Name string.

Comment: T can not be same and thats why it is "T", but you are checking on Interface defination right? Type name will not change from ICollection to any other. I am agree to what @jon has said. I want your help to understand comment "Not the safest of type comparison" with example.